# Real 5.1 Multichannel audio on Android Device

Tags: android, audio

I'm a trainee on a high tech company. since last week I'm on an observation about implementing 5.1 multichannel audio on Android device, once I saw there's a CHANNEL_OUT_5POINT1 enum on AudioFormat Class.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you build a device with high-end audio, please please please include audio recording from it as well!

Comment: Nice idea but I'm still wondering how to implement 5.1 audio, because later the android tablet I'm currently working on will have 4 speakers channel